change the color of the bar based on the value of the x axis
The current result What I want
Hi, I have this problem, I don't understand how to change the color of the bars based on the value of the X axis, I searched online but I didn't find a solution.
The need is to make the bars green if the X-axis value is >= 0 and red if < 0
In the code example the modification occurs only on the change in value of the Y axis, which I don't need.
Does anyone have a solution? Thank you!
Example code:
var options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Occorrenze',
        data: [2, 10, 45, 70, 47, 36, 7, 3] // _jSon.occorenze
    }],              
    chart: {
        height: 415,
        type: 'bar',
        foreColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                position: 'top'
            },
            colors: {
                /*
                    this block changes the color of the bar based on the value of the Y axis
                */
                ranges: [{
                    from: 0,
                    to: -100,
                    color: '#FF0000'
                }, {
                    from: 0,
                    to: 100,
                    color: '#02DFDE'
                }]
            }                        
        }
    },                
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val) {
            return val;
        },
        offsetY: -20,
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#fff"]
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        //type: 'Delta',
        type: 'category',
        categories: [3, 2, 1, 0, -0, -1, -2, 3], // _jSon.percentuali,
        labels: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val + "%";
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
        }                    
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: true,
        labels: {
            show: false,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val;
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return "Occorrenze"
                }
            }
        }
    }               
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#historical_occurrences"), options);
chart.render();


You can control bar colors dynamically, using the function version for
options.colors:
const options = {
    //......... series, chart, other options
    colors: [
         function({dataPointIndex, w}){
            const xValue = w.config.xaxis.categories[dataPointIndex];
            return isNegative(xValue) ? '#02DFDE' : '#FF0000';
        }
    ]
};

where I used
const isNegative = x => x < 0 || x === 0 && 1/x === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

to cover negative zero that you have set for categories.
Here's a snippet with your code and these changes:


const isNegative = x => x < 0 || x === 0 && 1/x === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
const options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Occorrenze',
        data: [2, 10, 45, 70, 47, 36, 7, 3] // _jSon.occorenze
    }],
    chart: {
        height: 415,
        type: 'bar',
        //foreColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    colors: [
        function({dataPointIndex, w}){
            const xValue = w.config.xaxis.categories[dataPointIndex];
            return isNegative(xValue) ? '#02DFDE' : '#FF0000';
        }
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                position: 'top'
            }
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val) {
            return val;
        },
        offsetY: -20,
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#fff"]
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        //type: 'Delta',
        type: 'category',
        categories: [3, 2, 1, 0, -0, -1, -2, -3], // _jSon.percentuali,
        labels: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val + "%";
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: true,
        labels: {
            show: false,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val;
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return "Occorrenze"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#historical_occurrences"), options).render();
<div id="historical_occurrences"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>



I see that your data and category values are set statically in the
code you posted, and by the look of the comments, they are obtained
by parsing some json input at a moment before the chart is constructed.
Then, the colors can also be set statically, at the same moment you get
the data and categories; to have apexcharts use an array for colors of
the same series, one has to enable
distributed: true
in plotOptions:
const categories = [3, 2, 1, 0, -0, -1, -2, -3]; // _jSon.occorenze
const data = [2, 10, 45, 70, 47, 36, 7, 3]; // _jSon.occorenze
const colors_s1 = categories.map(cat => isNegative(cat) ? '#02DFDE' : '#FF0000'); // s1 for first series

const options = {
    //......... series, chart, other options
    colors: [
         colors_s1
    ],
    plotOptions: {
        distributed: true,
        //......... other plotOptions options
    }
};

Snippet for this version:


const isNegative = x => x < 0 || x === 0 && 1/x === Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

const data = [2, 10, 45, 70, 47, 36, 7, 3]; // _jSon.percentuali,
const categories = [3, 2, 1, 0, -0, -1, -2, -3];  // _jSon.percentuali,
const colors_s1 = categories.map(cat => isNegative(cat) ? '#02DFDE' : '#FF0000');

const options = {
    series: [{
        name: 'Occorrenze',
        data
    }],
    chart: {
        height: 415,
        type: 'bar',
        //foreColor: '#ffffff'
    },
    colors: //[
        colors_s1,
    //],
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            distributed: true,
            dataLabels: {
                position: 'top'
            }
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function (val) {
            return val;
        },
        offsetY: -20,
        style: {
            fontSize: '12px',
            colors: ["#fff"]
        }
    },
    xaxis: {
        //type: 'Delta',
        type: 'category',
        categories,
        labels: {
            show: true,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val + "%";
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        show: true,
        labels: {
            show: false,
            formatter: function (val) {
                return val;
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            y: {
                formatter: function (val) {
                    return "Occorrenze"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#historical_occurrences"), options).render();
<div id="historical_occurrences"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>



